# $watch not updating when service object is updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller, angularjs-watch

I have discovered a perplexing circumstance in which the $scope.watch is not triggering as I would expect. I am hoping some of you AngularJS buffs out there can help shed some light on why Angular is behaving so peculiarly with $scope.watch and Service objects. As a note this was discovered while I was messing with the Ionic framework.

Below is an example of what I am running, and it works as expected (to be used to maintain state information during the session.)

**TL;DR:**
Watch doesn't fire on the controller when I update currentUser with a new userObject (currentUser = new userObject();) in my service. It does fire if I instead update each individual attribute of the object.

```
currentUser.name = 'Foo'; 
currentUser.email = 'foo@bar.com';
```

I am seeking guidance on why so I can better understand.

## Code

### Service (Working)

```
angular.module('app.services')
.service( 'UserService', function() {
    var userObject = function(){
        return {
            id: null,
            username: null,
            email: null,
            fullName: null,
            modified: null
        }
    };
    var currentUser = new userObject();

    var createUser = function(id, username, email, fullName, modified ){
        var newUserObject = new userObject();
        newUserObject.id = id;
        newUserObject.username = username;
        newUserObject.email = email;
        newUserObject.fullName = fullName;
        newUserObject.modified = (modified) ? modified : new Date();
        return newUserObject;
    };

    var setCurrentUser = function(userObj){
        console.log('First');
        console.dir(currentUser);

        setUserId(userObj.id);
        setUsername(userObj.username);
        setEmail(userObj.email);
        setFullName(userObj.fullName);         
        setModifiedDate(userObj.modified);

        console.log('Second');
        console.dir(currentUser);

        return currentUser;
    };

});
```

### Controller

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
.controller('DashboardCtrl', function ($scope, UserService) {
    var dashboard = this;

    dashboard.user = UserService.currentUser;

    $scope.$watch('UserService.currentUser', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal ){
            dashboard.user = newVal;
        }
    });

    var createdUser = UserService.createUser(
        1,
        'user1',
        'asdf@asdf.com',
        'Test User',
        new Date()
    );
    UserService.setCurrentUser(createdUser);
});
```

### View

```
<div ng-controller="DashboardCtrl as dashboard">
    <span bind="dashboard.user.fullName">Loading</span>
</div>
```

### Result

WAHOO! Loading is replaced on init with '' (null) and immediately after it is updated by the watch with 'Test User' (faster than the human eye unless debugging)

## Breaking Scenario

The code above works great. However I wanted to try and reduce code by reducing repetition of effort by creating a new UserObject and then setting that object as 'Current User'. The change I made was as follows (view and controller were unchanged):

### Service (Broken)

```
angular.module('app.services')
.service( 'UserService', function() {
    var userObject = function(){
        return {
            id: null,
            username: null,
            email: null,
            fullName: null,
            modified: null
        }
    };
    var currentUser = new userObject();

    var createUser = function(id, username, email, fullName, modified ){
        var newUserObject = new userObject();
        newUserObject.id = id;
        newUserObject.username = username;
        newUserObject.email = email;
        newUserObject.fullName = fullName;
        newUserObject.modified = (modified) ? modified : new Date();
        return newUserObject;
    };

    var setCurrentUser = function(userObj){
        console.log('First');
        console.dir(currentUser);

        // Set original 'currentUser' with a new UserObject passed by controller
        currentUser = userObj;            

        console.log('Second');
        console.dir(currentUser);

        return currentUser;
    };

});
```

### Result

Loading is replaced with '' on init (null) and $scope.watch never triggers in this scenario. My expectation is that the watch should be doing a deep watch on the object, and when I replace the object with a new one it should trigger that the object changed and trigger the watch.

The only thing I can figure, is that when I replace the currentUser object with a new object is that the delegates for $watch are also lost on that object. Does anyone have insight on how I can tell?

Phew.

Answer (score 2):

When you give a string to the `$watch` it checks that variable inside angular function, As you don't have `UserService.currentUser` inside your scope then that watcher function will never get fired.

For making your watch working, you need to use function instead of `string`, then that function will return an expression. By adding it in watcher function, so that it will get evaluated on each digest cycle & will perform dirty checking. If value gets change it will fire the watcher function

**Code**

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
   return UserService.currentUser;
}, function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal ){
        dashboard.user = newVal;
    }
});
```

Comment: But since nothing was changed aside from how the currentUser is updated in the service, not sure how that will affect the results. I will give it a whirl and update to see if the way its called changes how it behaves with a watch on objects being replaced entirely.

Comment: Update: using the function  approach instead of the string did not work, since the problem seems to be the service is not triggering the watch event (**only** when object is replaced with a new one. when you update individual attributes, it works perfectly which is why i am so confused)